# For video conversion what type of EC2 instance should I choose?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Standard, High-CPU, or High-Memory?

Comment: I guess it depends how fast you need the conversion done (or rather: would you accept lower throughput for a lower pricetag)

Answer (score 0):

Video conversion is a CPU-intensive task, I'd go for High-CPU.